# Get xml value of ElementTree Element

Tags: python, xml

I would like to get the xml value of an element in ElementTree. For example, if I had the code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<item>
<child>asd</child>
hello world
<ch>jkl</ch>
</item>
```

It would get me

```xml
<child>asd</child>
hello world
<ch>jkl</ch>
```

Here's what I tried so far:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.fromstring("""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<item>
<child>asd</child>
hello world
<ch>jkl</ch>
</item>""")
print(root.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on [Jack Fleeting's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74468921/14257302), I created a solution that is more general, not just relating to the xml I inserted.

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.fromstring("""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<item>
<child>asd</child>
hello world
<ch>jkl</ch>
</item>""")
for elem in root:
    print(ET.tostring(root.find(f'.//{elem.tag}')).decode())
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
print(ET.tostring(root.find('.//child')).decode(),ET.tostring(root.find('.//ch')).decode())
```

Or, more readable:

```
elems = ['child','ch']
for elem in elems:
    print(ET.tostring(doc.find(f'.//{elem}')).decode())
```

The output, based on the xml in your question, should be what you're looking for.